# Looking for sample code except for PCL/Tutorial

Tags: pcl, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking for some sample code except for codes on the page( http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials ) to get more knowledge about relationship between ROS and PCL. Could anybody tell me an information if knowing the web page that puts sample code? My goal is to build a people detection.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156831/looking-for-sample-code-except-for-pcl/tutorial/) by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 894 on 2014-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For example,

1. https://github.com/davetcoleman/point_cloud_lab
2. https://github.com/ankush-me/sandbox444/blob/master/display_pointCloud/src/display.cpp

I think that a code `display.cpp` on 2. is interesting, because this program can show images acquired from`fromROSMsg` on visualizer.
[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0